# How do I convert the generated python list numbers into a tensorflow dataset for onward feeding into an Artficial neural network model on colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


minWallThickness = 0.250
maxWallThickness = 0.375
minCurrentFlowRate = 320.0  #m3/HR
maxCurrentFlowRate = 600.0  #m3/HR
mycurrentFlRTList=[]
mywallTkList=[]

for x in range(5):
  wallThickness= round(random.uniform(minWallThickness, maxWallThickness), 4)
  mywallTkList.append(wallThickness)
  currentFlowRate = random.randint(320, 600)
  mycurrentFlRTList.append(currentFlowRate)

ls = [[mywallTkList],[mycurrentFlRTList]]
df = pd.DataFrame(ls)
print(df)
```

I would like to arrange `mywallTkList` and `mycurrentFlRTList` into a single tensorflow dataset which can be feed into an ANN model.

Comment: Do you want to create a dataset of `mywallTkList` as `X` and `mycurrentFlRTList` as `Y`? or you want to concat them as one `X`? or you want to feed them as 2 `X`s?

Comment: I would want to concat them as one X

Answer (score 0):

If i understood properly what yout want.
You could use the function `from_tensor_slices`.
You can see more about that [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(mywallTkList)
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. But I have two generated data in two list; mywallTkList and mycurrentFlRTList. I would like to have both of them in the  same place as mycurrentFlRTList, mywallTkList then subsequently pass them into tensor_slices as one dataset